# How to access logs on StdLib for my nodejs application

Tags: node.js, slack-api, botkit

I have a node js application for a slack-bot deployed on [StdLib](https://stdlib.com/) for a slack-bot application that I created using the following tutorial: [Build a serverless slack bot in 9 minutes with node js and stdlib](https://medium.com/slack-developer-blog/build-a-serverless-slack-bot-in-9-minutes-with-node-js-and-stdlib-b993cfa15358)

Now, everything is up and running, but I just want to see the logs of my application from StdLib.

I am already logged in as the authenticated user from my terminal and I am able to execute the command `lib up dev` successfully.

But, now when I try to view the logs using the command: `lib logs dev`, i get the following error:

`Error: You must be signed in as a service's owner or be part of the service's team to to view logs for a service`

Can anyone help me understand what i am doing wrong and how to access the dev logs from StdLib?

**EDIT:** I also tried logging in again by using `lib login --email <my email>` and then again tried `lib logs dev`, but it resulted in the same error as above.

Interestingly, even after logging in, if I do `lib info dev`, It gives me the error `Error: Bad Request: "<my username>" does not have permission to access "dev"`

Answer (score 0):

So, in case someone else is stuck with the same...

I was able to figure this out by checking out the following documentation:
https://docs.stdlib.com/main/#/creating-services/logging

basically I need to give the username and the app name in a specific fashion as follows:

`lib logs <my username>.<my app>[@dev]`

The error mentioned was kind of confusing and I could not decipher what I was doing wrong based on the error.